# Numpy where with array comparison

Tags: numpy, indexing, python-3.7

I have an array called `Y` which contains class labels. I want to find all the indexes of Y that match multiple values specified by a list labs.

In this case:

```
Y = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])
labs = [2,3]
```

How can I do something like `np.where(Y == labs)` that returns

```
array([1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11])
```

I know one possibility is to iterate through the list labs and do element wise comparison.  But I am looking for a more pythonic/numpy based solution which avoids looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`np.where(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) on an [**`np.isin(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) here:

```
>>> np.where(np.isin(Y, L))[0]
array([ 1,  2,  4,  5,  7,  8, 10, 11])
```

The `.isin(Y, L)` will give us an array of `True` and `False` where the item of `Y` matches an element in `L`:

```
>>> np.isin(Y, labs)
array([False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False,  True,  True])
```

and with `np.where(..)` we map the `True`s to the corresponding indices.

As [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57644832/numpy-where-with-array-comparison/57644859?noredirect=1#comment101745312_57644859) says, for small `L`s, we can write this as:

```
np.any([Y == li for li in labs],axis=0)
```

here, for each element in `labs`, we will check if `Y` is that elements, and we use `np.any(..)` to make a "chain of logical ORs" in between to fold it to a boolean.

Comment: `np.any([Y==i for i in labs],axis=0)` for this small example is actually faster than `isin`.  But `in1d` uses iteration like this when the 2nd argument is small enough.